# Не работает обработчик событий в вызываемой функции php

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, redbeanphp

Мне нужно вызвать функцию setButtons и в ней проверять нажатие нужных кнопок, но код в isset выполняется сам по себе. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить и что нужно сделать для корректной работы? Я новенький в php, не кидайтесь палками пожалуйста, для меня это важно

```
<?php
require "php/include_db.php";  

$array_buttons = array($_POST['location_button_1'], $_POST['location_button_2'], $_POST['location_button_3'], $_POST['location_button_4']);
$src = null;

$locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', 1);
$src = $locationInfo->location_image;
echo $src;
setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);

function setButton($locationInfo_travel){
            $arr_travels = explode(' ', $locationInfo_travel);
            for($i=0; $i<count($arr_travels); $i++){
            echo ", ", $arr_travels[$i];
            }
if(isset ($_POST['location_button_1'])){
            $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[0]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
            setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);
}if(isset ($_POST['location_button_2'])){
            $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[1]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
            setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);
}if(isset ($_POST['location_button_3'])){
            $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[2]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
}if(isset ($_POST['location_button_4'])){
            $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[3]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
 }
}
?>
```

Форма:

```
<div class="location_buttons_container">
                <div class="buttons_container">
                <form method="post" action="Game.php">
                    <ul class="buttons_menu">
                        <li>Локации</li>
                        <li ><span ><button id="location_button_1" name="location_button_1" >Главные ворота</button></span><em>3 сек.</em></li>
                        <li><span><button name="location_button_2">Торговый квартал</button></span><em>2 сек</em></li>
                        <li><span><button name="location_button_3">Замок</button></span><em>5 сек</em></li>
                        <li><span><button name="location_button_4">Гильдия</button></span><em>4 сек</em></li>
                    </ul>
                        </form>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: А зачем вы записываете пост данные в переменную `$array_buttons` если нигде её не используете?

Comment: Забыл убрать, можно не обращать на это внимание

Comment: А какой `isset()`  выполняется? Хоть пробовали проверить, что идёт в $_POST ? сделайте, как пример `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: isset выполняется 1 и 2.print выводит просто Array()

Comment: Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста все таки, в чем проблема???

Comment: Я хочу при вызове функции проверять нажатие одной из кнопок, но код в if срабатывает сам по себе. Как это сделать, что-бы все работало, с учетом рекурсии?